# bootup hangs on "started monitoring of lvm2 mirrors"

Tags: debian, startup

Recently I had some problems with hard disk. I think I solved that problems, but now my computer (with Debian) doesn't boot up. It hangs for several minutes on "started monitoring of lvm2 mirrors" step, then resumes and goes into maintance mode. I guess it's because some important file is broken, but how can I find out which one? Do you have any idea what goes on?